# Can we stream and watch youtube video using j2me(java)

Tags: java-me, midp-2.0

Can any one  How to play youtube videos on j2me java MIDlet?
I want to play videos from Rss Feed? 
My Input URL:
http://teluguone.com/tmdb/videos/Chinna-Smokes-Cigarette--Fabulous-Comedy-9533.html

Comment: The url you provided is not an RSS feed. If it where you would have a channel tag in it.

Comment: Sorrry,from the RSS feed Url only i got "http://teluguone.com/tmdb/videos/Chinna-Smokes-Cigarette--Fabulous-Comedy-9533.html" this Url need to play on device

Comment: When you click on YouTube button (on right down corner of the video) you are taken to the video original URL http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zqpAkb5TdXo&feature=player_embedded Try to open this other URL with javax.microedition.media.Manager.createPlayer

Comment: yaa ,I tried to open the youtube original URL to the Manager.createPlayer Method ,but i am facing the below Exception

javax.microedition.media.MediaException: Invalid locator: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zqpAkb5TdXo&feature=player_embedded

Comment: Please try to open the YouTube URL with MIDlet.platformRequest. It should open the handset browser and, if the handset is capable, play the video.

Comment: yaaa,I used Midlet PlatformRequest To open the Youtube video,it is asking,u need  Flashmedia or Html5 to open this video in series 40 device

Comment: According to http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_play_video_streaming_in_Java_ME you can use rtsp protocol with you tube http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Streaming_Protocol. Please, give it a try.

Comment: Hii,ya i tried for RTSP Protocol,it is Succeesfully Streaming and Playing in j2me(java),Can we able to Stream HttpProrocol (.Mp4) youTube Videos,Itried it for Nokia SDK 1.1 and Nokia Symbian Belle SDK 1.0 Device.it is giving the Exception,cannot create player for the provided url,i want to Stream and play the video "http://teluguone.com/tmdb/videos/Chinna-Smokes-Cigarette--Fabulous-Comedy-9533.html%22"

Comment: Please provide your rtsp url.

Comment: Actually,i dont have any requirement to play RTSP URL streaming,i just have taken sample RTSP url from youtube mobile Site "m.youtube.com" and i tried to play,My actual requirement is to stream and play the http://teluguone.com/tmdb/videos/Chinna-Smokes-Cigarette--Fabulous-Comedy-9533.html url....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the html page source code, search for the iframe tag with src pointing to http://www.youtube.com/embed/. The last part of the src url is the VIDEO_ID. For example, at http://www.youtube.com/embed/zqpAkb5TdXo URL VIDEO_ID is equal to zqpAkb5TdXo.

Open http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/mobile/videos/VIDEO_ID and search the source code for media:content tags. These tags point to urls with type='video/3gpp' and rtsp protocol and can usually be opened by J2ME apps with [Manager.createPlayer(url)](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr135/javax/microedition/media/Manager.html#createPlayer(java.lang.String)).

Comment: Hii,Thanks for Reply,I got your answer,But in j2me(java)can we do Http  RealTime Video Streaming?and also In j2me any special Html parsers are available,why because all the available parser in j2se,Jsoup Parser,Html Parsrer,Jericho Html Parser are not working in j2me,I want to Extract the iframe tag and  media:content tag information

Comment: Read the html page to memory, store it in a String and use indexOf and substring methods. You should be able to get the iframe tag this way.

Comment: Hii Telmo Pimentel Mota, your answer is not working,now i dont know wt happend,i am not able to extract the RTSP link,when i try to open this url http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/mobile/videos/zqpAkb5TdXo,  i am facing problem,can you help me out......and ,once you check my Actual link,which is to be played on my Device,Here the link http://teluguone.com/tmdb/videos/Chinna-Smokes-Cigarette--Fabulous-Comedy-9533.html

Comment: Read the url content to an String object named htmlContent, then: int mediaIndex = htmlContent.indexOf("<media:content"); int rtspIndex = htmlContent.indexOf("rtsp://", mediaIndex); int spaceIndex = htmlContent.indexOf(" ", rtspIndex); String url = htmlContent.substring(rtspIndex, spaceIndex -1);

Comment: thanks Telmo Pimentel Mota,But My Actual Problem is with this URL gdata.youtube.com/feeds/mobile/videos/zqpAkb5TdXo,some times the url is not opening in Brower,some times ,it is working,i checked it now,it is opening in my Brower,So my parsing code is working

Comment: You might have connectivity problems. When the YouTube url fails to load, does the main YouTube site also fails?

Comment: Hii Telmo Pimentel Mota, when i try to parse this URL: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/mobile/videos/Nrz2vpww41s for RTSP Link  ,My Code is giving Exception,after that When i try to open the above URL in browser,it is saying:you have chooosen to open 
Nrz2vpww41s this file
which is a: application/atom+xml(1.2 KB)
from:http://gdata.youtube.com
what should firefox do with this file?,For this any alternate Solution?